# Открывается много процессов в диспечере

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Делаю для себя софт и когда собираю вот так pyinstaller --onefile tyti.pyw
Открывает очень много процессов в диспечере видно, у меня озу 18гиг и стрелка не работает, из за 100% нагрузки, а когда код запускаю py то норм а exe после сборки то жесть

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init()
import datetime as dt
import os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os, binascii, hashlib, base58, ecdsa
import requests

def ripemd160(x):
    d = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    d.update(x)
    return d

r = 0

cores=2


#print(Fore.BLUE + "===============Searching Initiated============")
#print(Fore.BLUE + "===============Searching Initiated============")
#print(Fore.BLUE + "===============Searching Initiated============")
#print(Fore.BLUE + "===============Searching Initiated============")

def seek(r):
    global num_threads
    LOG_EVERY_N = 500
    start_time = dt.datetime.today().timestamp()
    i = 0
    #print(Fore.GREEN + "Core " + str(r) +":  Searching Private Key..")
    while True:
        i=i+1
        # generate private key , uncompressed WIF starts with "5"
        priv_key = os.urandom(32)
        fullkey = '80' + binascii.hexlify(priv_key).decode()
        sha256a = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(fullkey)).hexdigest()
        sha256b = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(sha256a)).hexdigest()
        WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(fullkey+sha256b[:8]))

        # get public key , uncompressed address starts with "1"
        sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(priv_key, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
        vk = sk.get_verifying_key()
        publ_key = '04' + binascii.hexlify(vk.to_string()).decode()
        hash160 = ripemd160(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(publ_key)).digest()).digest()
        publ_addr_a = b"\x00" + hash160
        checksum = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(publ_addr_a).digest()).digest()[:4]
        publ_addr_b = base58.b58encode(publ_addr_a + checksum)
        priv = WIF.decode()
        pub = publ_addr_b.decode()
        time_diff = dt.datetime.today().timestamp() - start_time
        if (i % LOG_EVERY_N) == 0:
            #print('Core :'+str(r)+" K/s = "+ str(i / time_diff))
        #print ('Worker '+str(r)+':'+ str(i) + '.-  # '+pub + ' # -------- # '+ priv+' # ')
                    pub = pub + '\n'
        # with open('results/adres.txt', 'a') as w:
            # w.write(f'{pub}')
        # with open('results/privat.txt', 'a') as w:
            # w.write(f'{priv}' + '\n')
        filename = '1.txt'
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                if pub in line:
                    msg = "\nPublic: " + str(pub) + " ---- Private: " + str(priv) + "YEI"
                    f = open('wallets.txt','a')
                    f.write(priv)
                    f.write('     ')
                    f.write(pub)
                    f.write('\n')
                    f.close()
                    time.sleep(30)
                    #print (Fore.RED + 'YOU JUST WON A BRAND NEW CAR!!! ---- ' +datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), pub, priv)
                    break
                    

contador=0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for r in range(cores):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=seek, args=(r,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```